# Syntax error when creating a MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1064

I have some problems trying to do a trigger.

Here is my MySQL query for the trigger:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER `aggiornaProduzione`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `strutture` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE temp bigint;
IF ( tipo=1/*mercato*/ AND old.livello <> new.livello )
THEN (
    SELECT round(2*livello*livello + 13.8*livello)
    FROM strutture WHERE tipo=1 AND city=old.city INTO temp;
    WHILE (temp%6<>0) temp=temp+1;
    END WHILE;
    UPDATE strutture SET produzione=temp WHERE city=new.city AND tipo=1;
    )
END IF;
END //
```

And the error is

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '; WHILE (temp%6<>0) temp=temp+1; END WHILE; UPDATE strutture SET ' at line 8

Does someone have an idea why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the parentheses around your `THEN` clause.  Also your `WHILE` clause is syntactically incorrect:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER `aggiornaProduzione`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `strutture` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE temp bigint;
IF ( tipo=1/*mercato*/ AND old.livello <> new.livello )
THEN
    SELECT round(2*livello*livello + 13.8*livello)
    FROM strutture WHERE tipo=1 AND city=old.city INTO temp;
    WHILE temp%6<>0 DO
      SET temp=temp+1;
    END WHILE;
    UPDATE strutture SET produzione=temp WHERE city=new.city AND tipo=1;
END IF;
END //
```

Comment: it'sstill not working, same error
    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'temp=temp+1; END WHILE; UPDATE strutture SET produzione=temp WHERE cit' at line 9

Comment: @Sanci: Well, for a start that's *not* the same error.  Now you need to look at the `WHILE` clause: in particular, it should be `WHILE temp%6<>0 DO SET temp=temp+1; END WHILE;`.  See my edit.

Comment: Yep, we're near the solution. Now there's this last error i suppose, because it's on last line:
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '//' at line 14

Comment: I removed the final // and now it works! Thanky you, you saved my day !